# My C# order program doesn't calculate correctly

Tags: c#

I need some help with my C# program.  It is supposed to ask how many is in the party, then the user enters their entree price if they want a drink adds that and then takes in a discount. The problem I am having is that if I do more than one in the party and they both get a discount it's not giving the correct results. Here is my code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int inParty = 0;
        int discoutSelection = 0;
        double entreeAmount = 0;
        int drinkSelection = 0;
        double drinkPrice = 1.25;
        double discount = 0;
        double orderAmount = 0;
        double tax = 0.07;
        double taxAmount = 0;
        double finalTotal = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("**********Welcome to K&W**********\n\n");

        Console.Write("How many are in your part?  ");
        inParty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while(inParty > 0)
        {
            inParty--;

            Console.Write("\nEnter your entree amount:  $");
            entreeAmount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Convert.ToDouble(orderAmount += entreeAmount);

            Console.Write("Do you want a drink, enter 1 for yes or another number for no.  ");
            drinkSelection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (drinkSelection == 1)
            {
                Convert.ToDouble(orderAmount += drinkPrice);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tNo drink at this time");
            }

            Console.Write("\nPlease choose a discount, enter 1 for senior, 2 for child or 3 for none:  ");
            discoutSelection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (discoutSelection == 1)
            {
                //Convert.ToDouble(discount = 0.10);
                orderAmount = Convert.ToDouble(orderAmount * 0.90);

            }
            if (discoutSelection == 2)
            {
                //Convert.ToDouble(discount = 0.20);
                orderAmount = Convert.ToDouble(orderAmount * 0.80);

            }

            finalTotal += Convert.ToDouble(orderAmount);
            entreeAmount = 0;
            drinkSelection = 0;
            discoutSelection = 0;
            orderAmount = 0;

        }

        taxAmount = Convert.ToDouble(orderAmount * tax);
        finalTotal = Convert.ToDouble(orderAmount + taxAmount);

        Console.WriteLine("\nYour bill is below:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Your subtotal is\t{0:C}", orderAmount);
        Console.WriteLine("Tax amount is\t{0:C}", taxAmount);
        Console.WriteLine("Your final bill is:\t{0:C}", finalTotal);

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nThank you for your order come again soom!!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should use type `decimal` for money values. It's much more accurate when doing calculations like this.

Comment: It would also help if you told us what the expected values were and what values you are actually getting.

Comment: ***UAFD***  *(Use A F###ing Debugger)*  Set a Breakpoint, Step through your code, examine your variables.

Comment: Your `orderAmount` variable is set back to 0 at the end of your while loop. You are only calculating the `orderAmount` of the last guy in the party

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation at the end of the task is wrong. You are using the wrong variable

```
double subTotal = finalAmount;
taxAmount = Convert.ToDouble(finalTotal * tax);
finalTotal = Convert.ToDouble(finalTotal + taxAmount);
```

orderAmount is reset to zero at the end of each loop

```
Console.WriteLine("\nYour bill is below:\n");
Console.WriteLine("Your subtotal is\t{0:C}", subTotal);
Console.WriteLine("Tax amount is\t{0:C}", taxAmount);
Console.WriteLine("Your final bill is:\t{0:C}", finalTotal);
```

And finally, you should use the decimal datatype when making calculations involving money values.

Comment: Only thing I'd add to this is that it'd be clearer if there were some classes to hold the values & which could do their own calculations.

Comment: The don't teach about classes in college, and that seems like class project.

Comment: @Claudius, uhhh, what college did you go to? classes were taught in my first programming course.